# MS-SQL Server search table using assembled criteria

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a search page that returns results according to the criteria nominated and this works ok when each criteria is OR but when I use AND it returns bad or no results. For example the search criteria might be...

```
A. Author = ""
B. Subject = ""
C. Keyword = ""
D. Dated = ""
```

Code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table 
WHERE Author = '" & strAuthor & "' 
  AND Subject = '" & strSubject & "' 
  AND Keyword = '" & strKeyword & "' 
  AND Dated = '" & strDated & "' "
```

Here I have used only 4 parameters whereas in fact there are quite a few more. But the example should explain the problem... to make this work I would need to be more specific such as "if A and B" or "B, C and D" but using any parameters that are blank or NULL will not work.

Now I could write in the criteria using a conditional statement like...

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table 
WHERE
    if strAuthor <> "" then 
        Author = '" & strAuthor & "'
    end if
    if strSubject <> "" then
        AND Subject = '" & strSubject & "'
    end if
```

and so on, except that writing `SELECT` strings like this does not work, just produces errors because the select string cannot contain additional code (that has been my finding).

If the options were only a few I could write separate select strings for each combination, but there are more than 10 different criteria which entail more than 3,628,800 combinations!

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No stored procedures are needed when using this code:

```
SQL = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ID <> ''"
    if len(strAuthor) > 3 then 
        SQL = SQL & " AND Author = '" & strAuthor & "'"
    end if
    if len(strSubject) > 3 then 
        SQL = SQL & " AND Subject LIKE '%" + Replace(strSubject, "'", "''") + "%'"
    end if  
    if len(strKeyword) > 3 then 
        SQL = SQL & " AND Description LIKE '%" + Replace(strKeyword, "'", "''") + "%'"
    end if  
    if strCatID <> "" then 
        SQL = SQL & " AND Category = '" & strCatID & "'"
    end if
SQL = SQL & " Order By Subject ASC "
```

The significance of the first line where it requests ID is to serve as a generic placeholder so that all following parameters can be prefixed with "AND".

If a variable is empty it is not included, so only those specified are used.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are having 2 options:

a) Create a stored procedure  and have some default value for all the columns, and in case if user doesn't pass any value, the query would run with the default value for that column.

b) Impose the rule on the front end to always select a value for all the columns.

Comment: Can you please provide an example?

Comment: Actually, there is no need of a stored procedure as I have worked out how to assemble the string using if/else conditions. Will post my solution here later.